# Problem using Git as a Deployment Tool by branch

Tags: git, bash, ssh, post-update

I am trying to create a post update script and use git as a deployment tool on a remote server.

My post-update script looks something like this

```
git update-server-info

for ref in $@;do
                echo $ref
                if [ "$ref"  = "refs/heads/production" ]
                then
                        ssh git@myProductionServer.com GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/test git checkout -f production
                fi
done
```

However, when I run that, an error comes back that says:

```
Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Which doesn't make any sense because I am able to run git commands from within the directory over ssh.
[image]

Is there something else that I need to be doing in my post-update script?

---

**Solution**

I added the `GIT_DIR` variable, so now my command looks like:

```
ssh git@myProductionServer.com GIT_DIR=/home/www/test/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/test git checkout -f production
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable - try the following:

```
ssh git@myProductionServer.com GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/test GIT_DIR=/home/www/test/.git git checkout -f production
```

The rules about `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` (and their equivalents, `--git-dir=<>` and `--work-tree=<>`) are so counter-intuitive to me that I now make it a rule that if I'm setting either one of them, I should set both, and furthermore make sure that they're both set to absolute paths.

Comment: That's it. The working directory of your SSH session will probably be the home directory of `git` – something like `/home/git`.